# Is it possible to specify which NetworkInterceptor to run before all other in Android Parse SDK?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a NetworkInterceptor that checks if there is an internet connection the device is currently connected to. The problem is, it seems to still run the ParseDecompressInterceptor first, which causes this issue [#355](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/355)

Is it possible to specify to run my own custom NetworkInterceptor before al others to fix this problem and especially to show a custom message to the users when there is no internet connection?